# Launching exe and bat files with InstallShield 2010

Tags: installshield, exe, batch-file, launch

I have to make an msi installer for an application. That app requires Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime and MySQL Server and i wish to launch installers from mine. I've been searching solutions,and tried to create a custom action of Launch exe file for launching them. I think action is right. Then I put this action in the tab Sequences and Commands at the end of all execute procces.When installation finishes, it seems that installer tries to launch exe files, but lauches an error message.
 Also I have to launch  bat file that executes MySQL scrpit to load a bbdd dump, but after a deep search I don't see anything helpìng (or I don't know how to search for it properly in English, sorry). 
Anyone knows a good tutorial explaining these things?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done through prerequisites:

- http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/IHelpMergeModules.htm
- http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/IHelpSetPrereqCustom.htm